# adapt javascript close window to close after 3 seconds?

Tags: javascript

can someone please help me, im really new to javascript, and im trying to automatically close a jquery shadow box window.

This script closes the shadow box window, but it does it straight away, is there a way i can set a 3 second time delay to this, by using timeout? and could someone please show me how i would do this.

thanks

```
<script>
window.parent.Shadowbox.close();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout)

```
setTimeout(window.parent.Shadowbox.close, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use *setTimeout* function. See: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Comment: @mika: They promote bad coding style and aren't a wiki, so you can't change the content. Anyways, the MDN has better articles: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout

Comment: @Blender Please list one single wrong piece of information that they promote, I never found myself misguided by their site and actually find it really helpful and more user-friendly than W3C specs (often not properly applied by vendors)

Comment: @mika Just check the link I've posted for the why - [w3fools.com](http://w3fools.com)

Comment: @Blender This does not really answer my question :-) I'm actually gonna open new question with that matter- see you there?

Comment: @Blender  Voila :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14803018/is-w3schools-a-valid-reference

Comment: Wow, I did not know that is is so controversial. But certainly well positioned in Google.

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
<script>
setTimeout(function(){ window.parent.Shadowbox.close(); }, 3000);
</script>
```